# How can I combine two result sets by a common column?

Tags: sql-server

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this.

Given two tables (ID is primary key, no duplicates):

```
 TblQtyNew            TblQtyUsed

ID | QtyNew          ID | QtyUsed
1    15              1    7
2    18              3    21
```

How can I obtain the following result?

```
ID | QtyNew | QtyUsed
1    15        7
2    18        NULL
3    NULL      21
```

The only solution I have come up with involves a UNION on the ID column then two left joins:

```
(SELECT ID FROM TblQtyNew) UNION (SELECT ID FROM TblQtyUsed) as IDs
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT QtyNew FROM TblQtyNew) ON TblQtyNew.ID = IDs.ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT QtyUsed FROM TblQtyUsed) ON TblQtyUsed.ID = IDs.ID
```

Is there a more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full join and coalesce in id as below:

```
select coalesce(t1.id,t2.id) as Id, Qtynew, QtYused 
    from #table1 t1 full join #table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
```

Output:

```
    +----+--------+---------+
    | Id | Qtynew | QtYused |
    +----+--------+---------+
    |  1 | 15     | 7       |
    |  2 | 18     | NULL    |
    |  3 | NULL   | 21      |
    +----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Coalesce! I knew it was staring me in the face!

Answer (score 1):

You want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.ID,T2.ID) as ID, T1.QtyNew, T2.QtyUsed
FROM TblQtyNew T1
FULL OUTER JOIN TblQtyUsed T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: That will give `NULL` instead of ID 3

Answer (score 1):

Use `FULL JOIN` and `Case`:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (id int , QtyNew  int);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE( id int , QtyUsed int);

insert into @T1 values (1,15),(2,18);
insert into @T2 values (1,7),(3,21);

SELECT ID = case when T1.ID IS not Null then T1.ID else T2.ID end, T1.QtyNew, T2.QtyUsed
FROM  @T1 T1
full JOIN  @T2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
Order by ID;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NIAMO44053)

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
SELECT ID,SUM(ISNULL(QtyNew)) AS QtyNew,SUM(ISNULL(QtyUsed)) AS QtyUsed
FROM (
    SELECT ID,QtyNew,NULL AS QtyUsed  FROM TblQtyNew
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,NULL QtyNew, QtyUsed FROM TblQtyUsed
) AS t
GROUP BY ID
```

2.

```
SELECT COALESCE(n.ID,U.ID) AS ID,n.QtyNew,u.QtyUsed
FROM TblQtyNew AS n FULL OUTER JOIN TblQtyUsed AS u ON n.ID=u.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I intentionally trying alternate method.

```
declare @TblQtyNew  table (ID int,QtyNew int)
insert into @TblQtyNew VALUES
(1,15)           
,(2,18)

  declare @TblQtyUsed  table ( ID int, QtyUsed int)
  insert into @TblQtyUsed VALUES
 (1 ,7 )
 ,(3 ,21)   

 ;with CTE as
 (
 select a.id,QtyNew,b.QtyUsed from @TblQtyNew a
inner join @TblQtyUsed b on a.id=b.ID
)
select * from CTE
union all
select  a.id,QtyNew,null
from @TblQtyNew a
where not exists(select id from cte c where c.id=a.id)

union all
select  a.id,null,QtyUsed
from  @TblQtyUsed a
where not exists(select id from cte c where c.id=a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id, QtyNew, QtyUsed
from TblQtyNew Full outer join TblQtyUsed
on TblQtyNew.ID=TBLQtyUsed.ID
```